# Remove special character and one character after that

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have some strings that have custom color variables which begins with "§"-character and after that have one character as a color definition. So the string looks like this: `§fc§9o§7l§1o§fr` and I want to parse it so it looks like this: `color`.

I have searched about `preg_replace`, `str_replace`, `substr` and `strstr` but can't figure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer from the finnish version of 4chan, I'll post it here too:

`$string = preg_replace('/\§./', '', $string);`